# Loading local html from an array in xcode

Tags: html, ios, arrays, nsstring, nsarray

I am attempting to load a locally hosted html file into a webview from an array. it looks something like this

```
_siteAddresses = [[NSArray alloc]
                      initWithObjects:@"file://localhost/var/mobile/Application/${APP_ID}/First Pentecostal Seminary.app/First_Pentecostal_Seminary/Main.html",...
```

with the corresponding code being

```
NSString *urlString = [_siteAddresses
                       objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

self.detailViewController.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

[self.detailViewController.webView loadRequest:request];
```

What am I doing wrong...is it my coding or perhaps the html coding (I believe there may be some java in there)

Comment: Read the comments in Rob's answer to see what worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two thoughts:

1. That example file URL doesn't look right. How did you construct that? If it was something from your bundle on your device, I'd expect something more like:

   ```
   file:///var/mobile/Applications/9E670C3C-C8B1-4B09-AE66-B43F7DB29F4D/First Pentecostal Seminary.app/...
   ```

   Obviously, you have to programmatically determine this URL by using `NSBundle` instance method `URLForResource` or by using the bundle's `bundleURL` and then adding the appropriate path components.
2. You should (a) specify the view controller to be the `delegate` for your web view; and then (b) implement `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` and look at the error there, and it will inform you what the error was, if any.

---

For example, I have a file, `test.html` sitting in my bundle, which I can load into a web view like so:

```
NSURL *bundleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL];
NSURL *url = [bundleURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.html"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

I have set up my view controller as the delegate for the web view and have the following `didFailLoadWithError`:

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%s: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
}
```

So, when I tried to load a request with an invalid URL this time (`test2.html`, which I do not have in my bundle), I get the following error:

> 2014-02-26 23:35:43.593 MyApp[3531:70b] -[ViewController webView:didFailLoadWithError:]: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not found on this server." UserInfo=0x8c32f40 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///Users/user/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF/MyApp.app/test2.html, NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///Users/user/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF/MyApp.app/test2.html, NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was not found on this server., NSUnderlyingError=0x10424c90 "The requested URL was not found on this server."}

Comment: Just to clarify are you saying that the ${APP_ID} is wrong or the use of localhost

Comment: @OmnicronCS Personally, I'm suspect about both. The `file://` URL I provided as an example is a valid one I got from `URLForResource`. Generally, I'd just have string literals with the relative local path within the bundle, and then use those `NSBundle` methods I reference above to determine the full URL at runtime.

Comment: @OmnicronCS By the way, I'd also manually inspect the bundle (e.g. find the bundle sitting in your Xcode project's `Products` folder; choose "Show in Finder" and once looking at it in Finder, choose "Show Package Contents") and make sure (a) the files are there at all (because it's too easy to add files to a project and accidentally neglect to include them in the bundle); and (b) the files are where you think they are (because folders in Xcode don't always translate to subdirectories in the bundle; it depends upon how the items were added to the project).

Comment: ...The code was a compilation of two answers from similar questions.  How should I implement the webView:didFailLoadWithError:...the only examples I have seen indicate no internet connection

Comment: Oddly enough I cannot select "Show in Finder" from the product.  I did check my build phases and saw that the files are listed as resources.

Comment: @OmnicronCS See my revised example of trivial `didFailLoadWithError`, which correctly reports errors with file URLs, too. Regarding your "I cannot select 'Show in Finder'" from the product", you're selecting the `.app` file in the `Products` folder at the end of the project? Is it in red (which means you need to do a build)?

Comment: @OmnicronCS You said "I did check my build phases and saw that the files are listed as resources". That's not enough: You really want to confirm that your "First_Pentecostal_Seminary" directory really exists (often bundle directory structure is flattened when added to the bundle unless you chose the "Create folder references for any added folders" when adding the files to your project, at which point, the folder appears in blue in Xcode, not yellow).

Comment: you were right on both accounts I will build and follow your advice thanks for your patience with me...

Comment: all of the files are there...I am looking now to try your example.  I think that is going to be my answer.

Comment: @OmnicronCS Very good. And the question is not only whether they're there in the bundle, but rather whether they're in the root of the bundle, or whether the folder references are there. Good luck.

Comment: thank you for all of your work...Your code did the trick.  I needed to make this 
`NSURL *bundleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL];
NSURL *url = [bundleURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.html"];` 
the method I used to reference the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code   

UIWebView *documentsWebView=[[UIWebView alloc]init];
documentsWebView.delegate=self;
documentsWebView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 616);  
documentsWebView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];  
[self.view addSubview:documentsWebView];    
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[_siteAddresses
                   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];  
[documentsWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: I like your approach my only problem with this is that this is that I am loading both local and internet hosted webpages from an array.

Comment: would that be practical with internet hosted pages as well?